# How to convert to asp.net razor syntax from webforms the following?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms

How can I convert the following statement into razor syntax? `OnDocumentReady` Method accepts `Action` as a parameter

```
<%
    Html.Telerik()
    .OnDocumentReady(() => {
        %>$("#searchbox").setAutocomplete('<%=Url.Action(MVC.Search.All())%>');<%
    }).Render();
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@(Html
    .Telerik()
    .ScriptRegistrar()
    .OnDocumentReady(
        @<text>
            $("#searchbox").setAutocomplete('@Url.Action(MVC.Search.All())');
         </text>
    )
)
```

Also notice that you were missing a `ScriptRegistrar` call.

---

UPDATE:

You might also try this if you are using an older version of Telerik extensions:

```
@{Html
    .Telerik()
    .ScriptRegistrar()
    .OnDocumentReady(
        @<text>
            $("#searchbox").setAutocomplete('@Url.Action(MVC.Search.All())');
         </text>
    )
    .Render();
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have removed some lines. With such syntax it shows error "; expected" after </text>. When I insert ";" then it throws exception "CS1593: Delegate 'System.Func<object,object>' does not take 0 arguments"

Comment: @Cheburek, I have tested this with the latest version of TelerikMvcExtensions (which is designed for ASP.NET MVC 3) and it worked fine. If you are using some old version it is possible that it is not compatible with Razor. I have updated my post with another example that you might try if you are using an older version (not sure if it will work). You should maybe even remove the `ScriptRegistrar()` call because I have added it in my answer thinking that you forgot it but maybe in older versions it was not necessary.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is with older telerik version (I've tried your updated version). I have Telerik 2011.2.712.340. Perhaps I need to update it to the latest one, but project is large so it could take more time than expected. When I finish I'll let you know if it works. Thank.

Comment: @Cheburek, doesn't my updated example that calls `.Render();` work?

Comment: Is it `CS1593`? Normally this should work assuming OnDocumentReady takes a `Func<object, object>` as argument. Let me download your version of Telerik and see.

Comment: @Cheburek, I have downloaded and tested with Telerik.Web.Mvc Version 2011.2.712.340 and both syntax that I have shown in my answer worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Created new MVC3 project, added reference to Telerik dll. Changed _Layout.cshtml to: "@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
<html><body>
<section id="main">@RenderBody()</section>
@(
  Html.Telerik()
  .ScriptRegistrar()
 .OnDocumentReady(() => {
  @<text>$(".box").hide();</text>
 })
)</body></html>" - Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

Comment: @Cheburek, didn't you read my answer? In your code you seem to be using some `() => { ... }`. Now look at my answer once again. But this time look carefully. Or if you can't concentrate use the Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V shortcut combinations on your keyboard.

Comment: Yes, it works. Sorry. Finally I saw the mistake! Instead of writing OnDocumentReady(@<text>$("#box").do();</text>) I was writing OnDocumentReady(()=>{@<text>$("#box").do();</text>})

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice comparison of those two  syntaxes:
 http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx